# Accordion in django include template

Tags: html, django, accordion

**Hi,i am using include django template to get another template into main.html. here is the line of code that i used to get appendix.html.  **

```
{% include "appendix.html" %}
```

**After i use this line of code, my accordion doesn't work. any idea on how to fix this?**
**here are my full code for main.html**

```
{% extends 'adminlte/barebase.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}

    <style type="text/css">
        [data-toggle="collapse"]:after {
            -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
            -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
            content: '\f107';
            font-family: 'Font Awesome\ 5 Free'; 
            font-weight: 900; /* Fix version 5.0.9 */
            transform: rotate(180deg) ;
            transition: all linear 0.25s;
            float: right;
        }   

        [data-toggle="collapse"].collapsed:after {
            transform: rotate(0deg) ;
        }
    </style>
         <div class="card">
                <div class="" style="width:20%,height:20%">
                    <div id="accordion" class="card-body" style="width:20%,height:20%">
                        <div class="title-section m-3">
                            <h5 style="display:inline-block;" class="title-section">Client Information</h5>
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true"></a>
                            <hr>
                        </div>
                        <content>
                            <div id="collapseOne" class="row m-2 collapse show" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                                <div class="col-lg-3">
                                    <label>{{form.ClientName|as_crispy_field}}</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-3">
                                    <label>{{form.TaxRef|as_crispy_field}}</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-3">
                                    <label>{{ form.Period_Employement|as_crispy_field }}</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-3">
                                    <label> {{ form.Basis_Period|as_crispy_field }}</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </content>
                        <div class="title-section mt-4 m-3">
                            <h5 style="display:inline-block;" class="title-section">Testing</h5>
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="true"></a>
                            <hr>
                        </div>
                        <content>
                            {% include "appendix.html" %} 
                        </content>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
{% block content %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

firstly at last line -- put {% endblock %}  instead of {% block content %}
and if this does not make then try {% extends "barebase.html" %} at first line instead if both the files i.e main.html and appendix.html are in same folder